# AIP classification with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm looking for some way to classify (AIP addon) emails through VBA. So far, we have used the Document Tagging Outlook addon. here I used the command:

```
Tag.applicationForMacro.MacroOutlookClassify(something)
```

Answer (score 0):

AIP labels are stored in Outlook items by using user properties. You can use the [PropertyAccessor.GetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty) method to get a custom property value:

```
Sub DemoPropertyAccessorGetProperty() 
 Dim PropName, Header As String 
 Dim oMail As Object 
 Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor 
 'Get first item in the inbox 
 Set oMail = _ 
 Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items(1) 
 'PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS 
 PropName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E" 
 'Obtain an instance of PropertyAccessor class 
 Set oPA = oMail.PropertyAccessor 
 'Call GetProperty 
 Header = oPA.GetProperty(PropName) 
 Debug.Print (Header) 
End Sub
```

I'd suggest using **MFCMapi** or **OutlookSpy** for exploring the low-level properties of Outlook items.